# Suppose $A$ is an invertible $n \times n$ matrix and $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with associated eigenvalue $4$. Convince yourself that $v$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Suppose $A$ is an invertible $n \times n$ matrix and $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with associated eigenvalue $4$. Convince yourself that $v$ is an eigenvector of the following matrices, and find the associated eigenvalues:
>
> 1. $A^4$, eigenvalue = ?
> 2. $A^{-1}$, eigenvalue = ?
> 3. $A + 4I_n$, eigenvalue = ?
> 4. $2A$, eigenvalue = ?

I started it off with number 1 thinking that the matrix would look like $\begin{bmatrix}4&0&0&0\\0&4&0&0\\0&0&0&4\\0&0&0&4\end{bmatrix}$ then would i simply just find the char. poly. by taking the $\det(A)$ to find its eigen values?

Comment: Hint: write $Av = 4v$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hints**

For 1:

Consider $A^4(v) = A(A(A(A(v))))$. What do you know about $A(v)$ and the properties of linear transformations that allow you to compute $A^4(v)$?.

For 2:

$A(v) = 4v$. If we assume $A^{-1}$ exists, we can rewrite this as:

$v = A^{-1}(4v) = 4A^{-1}(v)$. What can we conclude from this?

For 3:

If $A(v) = 4v$, then what is $(A+4I)(v) = A(v) + 4v$?

For 4:

If $A(v) = 4v$, then $2A(v) = 2(4v) = 8v$.